# whether event.preventDefault (); not support in internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have `event.preventDefault();` and `event.stopPropogation();` in my JavaScript function. It runs well in Chrome or Mozilla, but if I use Internet Explorer, my page refreshes when I press the submit button.

This is my JavaScript

```js
function hitung() {

  var e = (document.getElementById("ifin").value);
  var a = (document.getElementById("Furniture").value);
  var panjang = (document.getElementById("ipanjang").value);
  var ht = 0.0;
  var hf = 0.0;
  var total = 0.0;

  if (e == "hpl") {
    hf = 0.0;
  } else if (e == "cat") {
    hf = 0.5;
  } else {
    hf = 0.0;
  }
  if (a == "kitchen") {
    ht = 1.7;
  } else if (a == "meja") {
    ht = 2.3;
  } else {
    ht = 0.0;
  }
  total = panjang * ht + hf;
  document.getElementById("ototal").innerHTML = "Harga Total : Rp." + total.toFixed(2) + "0.000,00" + "<br>Sudah termasuk ongkir";
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropogation();
}
```

and this is my submit button

`<input type="submit" value="Submit" align="center" Onclick="hitung()" class="btn btn-success" >`

Is there any way to make this work in IE 8?

Comment: `internet explorer` which version? 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 or 11? It makes a HUGE difference as to whether you can use it or not (Ͼ˳Ͽ)

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=preventdefault As you can see it is supported in IE 9 and up.

Comment: im sorry, I have not said it before , i use internet explorer 8 @JaromandaX

Comment: debugging 101 - check the browser developer tools console for errors ... if your browser does not have developer tools console, it means it's so old that you should not be using it outside of [this web page](http://info.cern.ch/hypertext/WWW/TheProject.html) as the security issues would make the surfing the internet like swimming with sharks with a bloody nose :p

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn now i know the problem, thankss bro :)

Comment: what you then need to do is check if it is supported, and if not, just `return false`, I believe that should work in ie 8

Comment: misread your comment - deleting comment noise now :p

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in your code. It's `event.stopPropagation();` not `event.stopPropogation();`. I also don't see where you provide event variable. if it's handler, you should put it to `hitung(event)`. Happy coding! :)

Comment: my page keeps refreshing even if I fix my typo :(

Comment: have you added event variable as a parameter to handler function?

Comment: see comments on question. OP is using an 8 year old browser, IE8, so probably on windows XP, with no money left in their bank accounts

Comment: it does not influence, I use it or not my browser doesnt support :"
but thanks for answering me upvote 555

Comment: uh oh. that's bad.

Comment: @ShevaAthalla The traditional way to prevent default behavior is to return false. Note: not returning anything (ie. returning undefined) is not the same as returning false.

Answer (score 0):

To handle versions of IE8 and below, you need to check if the method exists, if not you then just `return false` instead. IE8 should be able to handle that.

Here is a basic way to check:

```
function eventHandler(e){
    ///////////////////////
    /// Place your code here
    ///////////////////////
    if (typeof e.preventDefault === "function") { 
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You would then handle a form submit like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/to/url" onsubmit="eventHandler(event)">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit your name">
<form>
```

Otherwise you would handle it via a click event like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/to/url">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="button" value="Submit your name" onclick="eventHandler(event)">
<form>
```

Comment: I've tried it but my page is still refreshed :( 
the i decided to change my `<input type="submit">` to `<input type="button">` and its worked
thanks for answering me, upvote!!

Comment: What html did you have? Because you don't show any code attached to the submit button

Comment: If you use a submit button I believe you need to attach the `onsubmit` event to the form

Comment: edited question, I apologize for not including it before